# Way to stop a subdomain using the .htaccess of main directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, rules

I have a subdomain on my server and I don't want it to use the .htaccess of the main directory, is this possible with .htaccess rules?

Comment: you mean a subdirectory? a subdomain would generally be hosted out of a completely separate directory tree than the main site. and no, you can't prevent .htaccess from applying to subdirs - apache processes them in the order it finds them as it parses through the directory tree.

Comment: If subdomain's DOCUMENT_ROOT is correctly set to sub-folder then it wouldn't even know of parent .htaccess hence won't use that.

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` rules are inherited from the parent *directory*, but AFAIK they shouldn't cross between different vhosts in Apache.

So long as your subdomain isn't rooted in a folder inside the root folder of the parent domain you should be fine.

Comment: my subdomain is rooted inside a folder of the parent domain